# How to fix error when comparing complex number to integer in python

Tags: python

Guys when i calculate **cagr** :

```
 c=(a/b)**(1/10)
```

i might get complex number : `(1.234556778+0.368957978)` based on input data of `a` and `b`.

so after when i want to compare `c`  to int :

```
c > 2
```

i get such error :

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'
```

How to fix this error ?

I tried making function but later i understood that the problem is not the formula but the comparision.

I am new in python and would appreciate if you could point how can i fix such error

Comment: What result do you expect? You can't compare complex numbers, not even mathematically. Or what would you say is larger, `i` or `1`?

Comment: i was thinking can i make number float or int but rounding it to 1.23 and then compare ?

Comment: is it possible to achive ?

Comment: No, it's not. Again, what would you say is larger: `i` or `1`? The answer is neither, there is no order relation on complex numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in part mathematical, as you cannot order complex numbers.  That is: `<` does never really make sense for complex numbers.

Depending on your needs, what you could do is check whether the result is a complex number or not:

```py
c = (a/b) ** (1/10)
if isinstance(c, complex):
    print("Cannot compare")
else:
    if c > 2:
        ...
```

**UPDATE:** Answering to your comment, if you want to "cheat", you could just take the *real* part of your complex number.  The code then looks like this:

```py
c = (a/b) ** (1/10)
if isinstance(c, complex):
    c = c.real
# c is now certainly a float...
if c > 2:
```

Since `c.real` is defined even if `c` is not complex but just a float, you can also just do it without the `if`, of course:

```py
c = (a/b) ** (1/10)
c = c.real
if c > 2:
    ...
```

Comment: i get an erro "complex" object has no attrobute 'complex'

Comment: @Chantel Sorry about that: it should be a comma in `isinstance()`, not a dot.  I've corrected it.